# 1 thread = 1,000,000 bytes. Is that true?

Tags: .net, windows, multithreading, operating-system, threadpool

So I was reading [this thread on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456401.aspx) that says

> Concurrency of this sort introduces many well-known difficulties.
>   First, threads are notoriously heavyweight; a thread by default
>   consumes a million bytes of virtual memory for its stack and many
>   other system resources.

and I'm wondering where that number comes from. Is there some constant in the Windows operating system that gives threads 1,000,000 bytes of memory? How was this number arrived on? Was it determined to be around the average number of bytes needed for a process?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [CreateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) regarding the `dwStackSize` parameter says

> dwStackSize [in]
>
> The initial size of the stack, in bytes. The system rounds this value to the nearest page. If this parameter is zero, the new thread uses the default size for the executable. For more information, see [Thread Stack Size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774(v=vs.85).aspx).

Following the link shows

> The default stack reservation size used by the linker is 1 MB.

So if you create a thread without specifying a stack size when calling CreateThread, the default allocation is 1 MB (1,048,576 bytes), which is roughly a million bytes. Why that number was chosen as the default isn't anything we can answer here, because it's highly unlikely that a MS employee who was sitting in the group that made that decision more than two decades ago (when Windows 95 and NT 4.0 were being developed) will read this post.

Answer (score 0):

By default windows allocates 1MB of virtual memory by default.  [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
explains more in depth